# How to get offset relative to a specific parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the offset of an element relative to *a specific parent* not the direct one and not the document.

I looked for that on the internet and found the [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) JQuery methods. But seems they don't help me in my situation ( relative to a specific parent)

Any help!

Comment: you can always subtract the two positions like: `$e.position().left - $e.parent().position().left`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
var offsetLeft = $('#myElement').position().left - $('#myElement').closest('#crazyAncestor').position().left;
var offsetTop = $('#myElement').position().top - $('#myElement').closest('#crazyAncestor').position().top;
```

Comment: Plus one for "crazy ancestor"  We've all got 'em

Comment: but this won't take positions of intermediate ancestors into account

Answer (score 0):

you need to subtract as OffSet implies the navigator window

```
var offset = GetOffSet( $("#a"), $("#b") );

function GetOffSet( elem, elemParent ) {
    return elemParent.position().left - elem.parent().position().left;
}
```

Comment: That would actually return a negative offset, as you're subtracting the child's offset from the parent's offset and not vice versa.

Comment: well, just change it then :D eehehe