# jQuery mousemove offset relative to listening element on bubbled event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

If I have jQuery listen for the `mousemove` event on an "outer" element, the `offsetX` and `offsetY` values give an offset relative to an "inner" element when the mouse is within that inner element and the event bubbles to the handler.

How can I always get the offset relative to the element to which the handler is attached?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/00mo3eeu/

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 40px;
}

.inner {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JS

```
$('.outer').mousemove(function(e) {
    console.log([e.offsetY, e.offsetX]);
});
```

Update: in case it's not clear, get the dot to follow the pointer even in the blue box http://jsfiddle.net/00mo3eeu/1/

Comment: try this maybe ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389527/how-to-get-offset-relative-to-a-specific-parent

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is my current solution and I welcome any suggestions to improve it.

```
function (e) {
  var y = e.pageY - $(e.currentTarget).offset().top
  var x = e.pageX - $(e.currentTarget).offset().left
  ...
}
```

Ideally this would be given as one of the properties on the event object, but I can't find one that matches.